# What is the sum of numbers between 250 and 350 which are divisible by 7?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic-progressions

> What is the sum of numbers between $250$ and $350$ which are divisible by $7$?

**My attempted solution:**

```
7|250|35
 |21 |
 -----
   40
   35
  ----
    5
```

The 1st number divisible by $7$ is: $(250-5)+7 = 252$.

```
7|350|50
 |35 |
 -----
    0
```

The last number divisible by $7$ is: $350$.

Total numbers between 250 and 350 divisible by $7$ is:

$((350-252)/7) + 1$

$ = (98/7)+1$

$ = 14+1$

$ = 15$

$ Sum = \frac{15}{2} [2 \cdot 252 + (15 - 1) \cdot 7 ]$

$ = \frac{15}{2} [2 \cdot 252 + 14 \cdot 7 ]$

$ = \frac{15}{2} [504 + 98 ]$

$ = \frac{15}{2} \cdot 602$

$ = 15 \cdot 301$

$ = 4515 $

**(Ans.)** $4515$

**Is there a more efficient way to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
252 + 259 + 266 + 273+\cdots\cdots+336+343+350
$$
Since this is an arithmetic sequence, i.e. the difference between each number and the next is the same in all cases, the **average** of all the numbers in the list must be the same as the average of the first one and the last one:
$$
\frac{252+350} 2 = 301
$$
Therefore the sum is $(301\times\text{the number of terms}).$

Since you have to add $7$ fourteen times, there are $15$ numbers, so the answer will be $301\times15.$

Comment: Nice alternative method!

Comment: This method takes lesser time to calculate than that of `gimusi`.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

The first divisible number is $252$ the last $350$ then

$$252+\dots+350=7(36+\dots+50)=7\left(\sum_{k=1}^{50}k-\sum_{k=1}^{35}k\right)$$

Comment: this is a very straightforward method.

Comment: @yahoo.com Also the method by Michael is very good! Bye